# Image blob working with Image from react native but not with FastImage

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, axios, blob, react-native-fast-image

I'm trying to retrive image from AWS s3, i'm presigning the url and fetching the image, but if teh result is tried with Image component from react-nativen everything is working but when using FastImage the image is not displayed

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { generatePreSignedUrl } from 'helpers/sign-urls-aws-s3';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
;
export function ImageFromAWSS3({ imageURL, style }) {
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const presignedURL = generatePreSignedUrl(imageURL);



  const fetchImage = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let config = {
      method: 'get',
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: imageURL,
      headers: {
        'X-Amz-Content-Sha256':
          'X-AMZ-CONTENT',
        'X-Amz-Date': presignedURL.X_Amz_Date,
        Authorization: presignedURL.Authorization,
      },
      responseType: 'blob', // Specify the response type as 'blob'
    };

    axios
      .request(config)
      .then(async response => {
        const blob = await response.data;
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
          setImage(reader.result);
          setLoading(false);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });

    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImage();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }
  return (
    <View>
      {image != null && (
        <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={style} resizeMode="contain" /> // this is working 

        <FastImage source={{ uri: image }} style={style} resizeMode="contain" /> //    this is not working
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I don't undersatnd why this is not working everything is the same.